# Autofill/Autocomplete not working, if the form has more than 200 input fields

Tags: html

I am working on a **HTML5 Form** which has more than 200 input fields, among these fields I need to autofill two fields basically which are name and email address, all other fields are marked as `autocomplete=off`.

It is observed autocomplete works only if total number of input fields in the form is *<= 200*, this is happening in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Hey @BijeshSomarajan , hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Comment: @shubh1834 , I do not have autocomplete="off"  in form tag  and have autocomplete setting for email and name. The issue is not resolved.

Comment: Can you please add your **HTML** and **CSS** code in the question, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: I have just discovered this very subtle limitation too.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing autocomplete="off" from <form> tag and enter autocomplete in input tags of name and email only.