# Google Chrome stops using saved password if more than 200 fields in form

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

I know [this has been asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62921196/309917) — without any solution — I ask again adding sample code.

**There is an issue, at least in Google Chrome v.91, which stops giving access to the user to saved passwords if there are more than 200 fields in the form.**

While this form with 199 fields **shows autocomplete for password** — i.e. you get access to saved passwords:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="0" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="4" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="5" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="6" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="7" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="8" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="9" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="10" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="11" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="12" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="13" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="14" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="15" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="16" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="17" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="18" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="19" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="20" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="21" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="22" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="23" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="24" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="25" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="26" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="27" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="28" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="29" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="30" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="31" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="32" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="33" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="34" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="35" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="36" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="37" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="38" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="39" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="40" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="41" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="42" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="43" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="44" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="45" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="46" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="47" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="48" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="49" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="50" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="51" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="52" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="53" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="54" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="55" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="56" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="57" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="58" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="59" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="60" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="61" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="62" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="63" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="64" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="65" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="66" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="67" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="68" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="69" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="70" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="71" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="72" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="73" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="74" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="75" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="76" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="77" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="78" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="79" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="80" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="81" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="82" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="83" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="84" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="85" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="86" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="87" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="88" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="89" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="90" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="91" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="92" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="93" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="94" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="95" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="96" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="97" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="98" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="99" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="100" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="101" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="102" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="103" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="104" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="105" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="106" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="107" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="108" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="109" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="110" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="111" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="112" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="113" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="114" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="115" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="116" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="117" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="118" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="119" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="120" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="121" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="122" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="123" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="124" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="125" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="126" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="127" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="128" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="129" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="130" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="131" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="132" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="133" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="134" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="135" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="136" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="137" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="138" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="139" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="140" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="141" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="142" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="143" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="144" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="145" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="146" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="147" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="148" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="149" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="150" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="151" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="152" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="153" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="154" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="155" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="156" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="157" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="158" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="159" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="160" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="161" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="162" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="163" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="164" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="165" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="166" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="167" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="168" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="169" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="170" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="171" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="172" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="173" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="174" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="175" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="176" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="177" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="178" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="179" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="180" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="181" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="182" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="183" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="184" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="185" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="186" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="187" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="188" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="189" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="190" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="191" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="192" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="193" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="194" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="195" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="196" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="197" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="198" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

in this one with 200 fields **autocomplete stops working** — i.e. user has no access to saved passwords

[image: no autocomplete]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="0" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="4" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="5" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="6" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="7" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="8" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="9" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="10" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="11" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="12" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="13" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="14" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="15" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="16" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="17" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="18" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="19" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="20" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="21" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="22" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="23" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="24" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="25" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="26" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="27" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="28" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="29" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="30" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="31" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="32" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="33" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="34" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="35" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="36" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="37" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="38" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="39" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="40" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="41" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="42" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="43" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="44" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="45" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="46" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="47" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="48" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="49" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="50" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="51" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="52" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="53" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="54" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="55" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="56" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="57" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="58" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="59" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="60" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="61" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="62" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="63" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="64" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="65" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="66" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="67" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="68" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="69" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="70" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="71" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="72" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="73" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="74" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="75" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="76" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="77" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="78" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="79" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="80" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="81" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="82" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="83" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="84" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="85" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="86" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="87" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="88" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="89" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="90" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="91" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="92" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="93" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="94" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="95" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="96" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="97" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="98" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="99" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="100" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="101" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="102" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="103" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="104" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="105" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="106" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="107" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="108" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="109" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="110" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="111" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="112" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="113" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="114" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="115" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="116" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="117" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="118" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="119" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="120" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="121" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="122" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="123" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="124" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="125" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="126" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="127" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="128" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="129" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="130" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="131" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="132" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="133" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="134" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="135" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="136" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="137" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="138" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="139" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="140" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="141" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="142" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="143" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="144" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="145" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="146" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="147" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="148" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="149" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="150" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="151" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="152" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="153" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="154" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="155" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="156" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="157" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="158" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="159" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="160" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="161" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="162" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="163" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="164" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="165" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="166" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="167" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="168" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="169" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="170" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="171" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="172" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="173" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="174" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="175" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="176" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="177" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="178" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="179" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="180" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="181" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="182" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="183" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="184" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="185" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="186" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="187" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="188" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="189" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="190" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="191" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="192" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="193" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="194" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="195" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="196" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="197" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="198" />
    <input type="radio" name="master" value="199" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If that’s the case you can only get around the problem by limiting the form fields. You might want to check the bug tracker of chromium and if you can’t find a bug related to that fill a bug report there.

Comment: At the moment I'm creating all `<input type="radio" />` as `type="hidden"` and then reverting after autocomplete does his job with `setTimeout(() => document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('input[name="master"]').forEach($i => $i.type = 'radio'), 500);` terrible workaround...